# Halmos' "Naive Set Theory" - Exercise on Equivalence Classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, set-theory

In Section 7 of Halmos' "Naive Set Theory" the following exercise is proposed:

> Exercise: show that $X/R$ [that is, the collection of the equivalence classes of elements of $X$ with respect to the equivalence relation $R$ in $X$] is indeed a set by exhibiting a condition that specifies exactly the subset $X/R$ of the power-set $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

**My attempt**
Up to this point in the book, a set can be constructed only by applying one of the following Axioms: Specification, Pairing, Union, Powers. Therefore it seems clear to me that given the set $X$ and the equivalence relation $R$ in it, we first construct the power-set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by applying the Axiom of Powers, then we extract $X/R$ by applying the Axiom of Specification in the following manner:

$$ X/R = \{Y\in\mathcal{P}(X)-\{\emptyset\}: [\exists x \in X:(\forall y \in Y, (x, y) \in R)]\}$$

in which we have an embedding set (namely $\mathcal{P}(X)-{\emptyset}$) and the specifying condition contains $Y$ as a "free variable" (it appears at least once without being preceded by a quantifier).

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, the above specification is not right. Therefore I changed it into:

$$ A = \{Y\in\mathcal{P}(X): [\exists x \in X:(y \in Y \iff (x,y) \in R)]\}$$

Now, we need to show that $A = X/R$.

In order to do so, we shall prove that if $Y \in A$ and $x \in Y$, then $Y = x/R$ (that is, $Y$ is the equivalence class of $x \in X$ modulo $R$). In fact, suppose $y \in Y$, then $(x, y) \in R$, hence $y \in x/R$ and, viceversa, suppose $y \in x/R$, then $(x, y) \in R$, hence $y \in Y$.

Since from this it is clear that $A \subseteq X/R$, it suffices to show that if $Y \in X/R$, then $Y \in A$. In fact, $Y \in X/R$ implies that $Y$ is the equivalence class of some $x \in X$ modulo $R$, hence there exists $x \in X$ such that $x \in Y$ (by the Reflexivity of $R$) and such that $Y$ contains exactly the elements to which $x$ stands in relation. Therefore, $Y \in A$.

Thus, the proof is concluded.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138284/discussion-on-question-by-matteo-menghini-halmos-naive-set-theory-exercise).

Comment: @Pedro Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for having moved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take a Simple Example to use through out this Answer.

$X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
We want Equivalence Classes MOD 3, that is we want ONLY valid $A=\{\{1,4,7\},\{2,5,8\},\{3,6,9\}\}$ & nothing else.
This $A$ has these Properties:
(P1) The union of the elements is X
(P2) The elements of A are Disjoint
(P3) Each Class is available in only 1 element of A and not in other elements of A
(P4) Each element of A contains only 1 Class & no other elements of X

Let us look at some invalid Cases, with the reasons:
$W1=\{\{1,4,7\},\{3,6,9\}\}$ : One Class is missing or union is not X [[ P1 ]]
$W2=\{\{1,4,7\},\{1,4,7,2,5,8\},\{3,6,9\}\}$ The Classes are not Disjoint & Class occurs in 2 elements [[ P2 & P3 ]]
$W3=\{\{1,4,7,2,5,8\},\{3,6,9\}\}$ : Two Classes are merged [[ P3 & P4 ]]
$W4=\{\{1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9\}\}$ : All Classes are merged [[ P3 & P4 ]]
$W5=\{\{1,4,7,3,6\},\{2,5,8,9\},\{3,6,9\}\}$ : Some Classes have extra elements [[ P4 ]]
$W6=\{\{1,4,7\},\{3,6,9\},\{1,4,7,3,6,9\}\}$ : Not All Classes are there but we have extra elements [[ P1 P2 P3 & P4 ]]

Here are one way we can eventually get the necessary Specification, using **Power Set of Power Set** :

$A = \{Y \in P(P(X)) :  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\exists y \in Y : x \in y)  \\
\ \ \ \ \}$
This satisfies P1 , by claiming that every element is X is there somewhere in some element of Y. This eliminates W1 & W2 but not W2 & W3 & W4 & W5.

$A = \{Y \in P(P(X)) :  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\exists y \in Y : x \in y) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\forall y,z \in Y : (x \in y \land x \in z \implies y = z))  \\
\ \ \ \ \}$
This satisfies P1 & P2 by claiming that when some element occurs in y & z, then y & z must be same. This eliminates W1 & W2 & W5 & W6 but not W3 & W4.

$A = \{Y \in P(P(X)) :  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\exists y \in Y : x \in y) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\forall y,z \in Y : (x \in y \land x \in z \implies y = z)) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall y \in Y : (\forall u,v \in y : (uRv))  \\
\ \ \ \ \}$
This satisfies P1 & P2 & P3 by claiming that when two u,v elements occur in y, then u,v must be in the relation R. This eliminates W1 & W2 & W3 & W4 & W5 & W6.

$A = \{Y \in P(P(X)) :  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\exists y \in Y : x \in y) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall x \in X : (\forall y,z \in Y : (x \in y \land x \in z \implies y = z)) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall y \in Y : (\forall u,v \in y : (uRv)) \land  \\
\ \ \ \ \forall y,z \in Y : (\exists u \in y , \exists v \in z : (uRv)) \implies y = z \\
\ \ \ \ \}$
This satisfies P1 & P2 & P3 & P4 by claiming that when two related u,v elements occur in y,z then y=z. This eliminates W1 & W2 & W3 & W4 & W5 & W6.
**We have thus eventually got the required Specification.**

In this MODULO 3 Example, I am not able to make some Invalid Case which goes through P1 & P2 & P3 but not through P4.
It may be the P4 can be Proved via P1 + P2 + P3 in which case we can simplify the Specification. I am listing it, assuming it may be necessary.

Comment: A comment on the Exercise given "Exercise: show that ... the collection of the equivalence classes of elements of X .... exhibiting a condition that specifies exactly the subset ... of the power-set P(X)" : We want Exactly 1 subset out of many (all) subsets !! Where can we get (all) those many subsets of the Power Set ?? I think that is a major clue !!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I see your point now and I have to admit that you manufactured a very precise set. However, I have just checked that the set specified in the edited part of myquestion satisfies all of your properties, hence I can not see why it isn't correct. Moreover, a minor nitpick I think, you are defining $A$ as a set of subsets of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ whereas it should be a set of subsets of $X$.

Comment: About your query about your Criteria : Take only 3 elements, 3,6,9 . In our Answer ,we want {3,6,9} but your Criteria will Permit {3} , {3,6} , {3,9} & {3,6,9} where there always exists x (=3) y in Y implies yR3 ! Yet this will not get all the y required.

Comment: I see what you mean : We want $Y$ but we get $A=\{Y\}$ ; I will fix that (currently taking a break) in a little while !! Typing the MathJAX is cumbersome. I have to remove the outer braces in $A=\{ Y \in \cdots \}$ all over !

Comment: Actually, my Criteria doesn't allow $\{3\}$ (or any other of the sets you have proposed) for if $3 \in Y$ and $Y \in A$ then there exists $x \in X$ such that $3Rx$, because $3 \in Y \iff 3Rx$. Henceforth, $x$ can be 3 or 6 or 9 (any other element won't do for then $3Rx$ doesn't hold). However, that means $6 \in Y$ and $9 \in Y$ because  whatever $x$ I choose it is true that $6Rx$ and $9Rx$ which is exactly the condition for 6 and 9 to belong to Y! In conclusion, $\{3\}$ can not happen.

Comment: When we are checking the sets $Y = \{3\}$ & $Y = \{3,6\}$ , we are limiting the y values to only those elements and it is true for all y values of elements of Y ! **Here, 9 can not enter because it is not in Y & we choose x=3.** The Criteria only claims that there exists x (where we choose 3) such that all elements y in Y have yR3. This Criteria will eliminate $Y = \{3,8\}$ & $Y = \{3,6,8\}$ when considering 8R3 ! But \{3\} , \{3,6\} , \{3,9\} & \{3,6,9\} will get through.

Comment: Actually, the equivalence entails that 9 is in Y, check the edited question for I changed it from last time.

Comment: I see this $A={Y∈P(X):[∃x∈X:(y∈Y⟺(x,y)∈R)]}$ at the moment. Let me be the "Criteria Checker" & you give me the sets one-by-one. You give me "3,8" , I reject. You give me "3,6,8" , I reject. You give me "3,6" , I choose x=3 & check whether 3R3 & 3R6 : PASS ! I might even choose x=9 & check 9R3 & 9R6 : PASS ! you give me "3,6,9" , I choose x=6 & check 6R3 & 6R6 & 6R9 : PASS ! [[ **"I think"** I know where you are going wrong. **"You are assuming"** that R can put values into Y whereas Y is fixed & then x is fixed & then Criteria Checker uses R to reject or PASS & R can not update x or Y. ]]

Comment: The problem is that by your line of reasoning, even the equivalence class of 3 modulo 3 defined to be the set {x∈X: x \equiv 3 \text{mod}(3)} gives a pass to {3,6}. However that is not the set in question! If it is written y∈Y⟺yR3 then that means that 3, 6, and 9 belong to Y (read the ⟸ part).

Comment: (1) In the set ${x∈X:x = 0mod(3)}$ , you give me 1 , I reject. You give me 2 , I reject. You give me 3 : PASS, 6 PASS, 9 PASS. You then make the set with all PASS elements "3,6,9" (2) Whether it is implication or BiDirection , y values are restricted to what Y we are currently given. When given "3,6" , only these y values will be taken with some x (we can choose x=3 x=6 x=9) to get PASS ! When given "2,5" , only these y values will be taken with some x (we can choose x=2 x=5 or x=8) to get PASS ! When given "8,9" , only these y values will be taken : reject because there is no suitable x !

Comment: When you give me 3, I only say PASS or reject. Why I will give 6 or 9 back ? Why will you give me 6 or 9 when that is not in Y ? That is why I was saying that R can not update x , y or Y. When we are checking xRy , then x , y , Y are all fixed. The BiDirection can not update the given elements.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, so let's try to do this way: could you please tell me where do I go wrong in the following line of reasoning? I want to prove that $Y = \{3\}$ is not in my $A$. Suppose it is, then there exists some $x \in X$ such that $y \in Y \iff xRy$ (I am quoting my specifying condition), where $R$ is the modulo 3 relation. Since $3 \in Y$, then $x$ is going to be something equivalent to 3 modulo 3. In that case it is clear that, whatever $x$ is, $xR6$ and $xR9$ both hold. [Continue below]

Comment: Let us come back to the specifiying condition for $Y$: $y \in Y \iff xRy$. That also means: $xRy \implies y \in Y$. In conclusion, both 6 and 9 must be in $Y$. Please let me know where I am doing wrong because I am getting very confused...

Comment: Indeed with y=3 [ 3Rx implies xR3 & this implies **y(=3) is in Y** ] But **this will not imply x(=3 or 6 or 9) is in Y** : In this case, 6 & 9 may or may not be in Y , depending on what Y ("3" or "3,6" or "3,6,9") we were given. Hope that clarifies ! We can continue after a gap , I have to take a break ! Meantime , I suggest to work out the Criteria with my way & your way to compare where it diverges !

Comment: This Question has been Answered here ( Correctly I hope ! ) & you can ask further clarifications about that Answer here. About why your Current Attempt is incorrect, that is a "New Different Question" & this Comment thread has become too long & "un-user-friendly" ! I suggest you Post a New Question with only your Attempt, asking what is wrong. I have worked out one Answer to that "New Different Question", but that requires "Diagrams & more text & formatting" which will not fit in comment boxes. @MatteoMenghini